# Powershell Azure Save-AzureWebsiteLog throws error with MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I am trying to download website logs for a specific website using powershell:

```
Save-AzureWebsiteLog -Name website1 -output file.zip
```

It throws an error about the maximum message size quota, I have searched for an answer but all I can find is setting this on the server web.config - wouldn't this be a setting for the client, as it is the one making the request for the response?

```
save-azurewebsitelog : The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the
quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
At line:1 char:1
+ save-azurewebsitelog -name website1 -output file.zip
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Save-AzureWebsiteLog], CommunicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.SaveAzureWebsiteLogCommand
```

I am asking if anyone knows how to set this MaxRecievedMessageSize to something higher than 65536 so that I can download my IIS logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can open an issue for this here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell
2. In the mean-while you can access your *scm* site and download your IIS logs from there by browsing to: https://{siteName}.scm.azurewebsites.net (provide your deployment credentials) and clicking on the **Diagnostics dump** link at the top.

   For more information on this scm site go here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about.aspx

Comment: I'm still hitting the 'quota' error with all current deployments. Is it still broke? has an issue been logged for it?

Comment: @JustSteve yes, it appears to be.  I just tried using the latest Azure PS cmdlets and get the same thing. Here's the open issue on it. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/26

Comment: FYI the repo you linked to is private

Answer (score 1):

I made this script as a workaround:-

```
$username = "<enter git deployment username>"
$password = "<enter git deployment password>"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$apiUrl = "https://<website name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/LogFiles/"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET 
try
{
$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($response.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.OriginalString)
$filepath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("c:\asdf\", "http1.zip")
$filestream = [System.IO.File]::Create($filepath)
$response.RawContentStream.WriteTo($filestream)
}
finally
{
$filestream.Close()
}
```

Comment: Sehgai  I am having this error, if you know the solution please let me know :Invoke-WebRequest : Server Error
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
At line:5 char:13
.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the log files exceed 65536, We will look at fixing this. in the meantime, please delete the OLD log files after downloading them, so you wont hit this issue.

Comment: what should we set our maximum to in the Azure portal to not hit this issue? 65K??